# Some collection

Tags: java

I'm needing to store a link structure. As a hierarchy, for example, x link, links children of x, y link, links children of y. Resorting to the use of java object id. I wonder if you have something like this in Java, any collection that does it for me.

Thanks!

Comment: Do you want a simple tree structure or a bi-partite graph ?

Comment: I'm sorry, I don't understand what you're asking for. Can you give some code example of what you would like to accomplish? Maybe start by modifying Bohemian's code below.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

AFAIK, there's no standard java [Collections](http://download.oracle.com/javase/1.4.2/docs/api/java/util/Collections.html) class for this.

However, it's not a tough class to write. Something like this would do:

```
class Node {
    List<Node> children = new ArrayList();

    public List<Node> getChildren() {
        return children;
    }
}
```